# Erro ao inserir imagem destacada e em mídia Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

estou tentando inserir imagens na mídia do wordpress, e em imagens destacadas, porém, independentemente se o arquivo é muito pequeno ou muito grande, ao carregar, me retorna uma mensagem de erro "Erro ao enviar. Tente mais tarde."
O que devo fazer para solucionar isto?

Esta sendo rodado em um servidor da Dream Host.
Obs: Tenho outro site Wordpress neste mesmo domínio, e o mesmo aceita imagens normalmente.

Comment: Tente descrever melhor as características do seu projeto. Esta rodando em ambiente local? em produção? qual o sistema operacional? Qual versão do WordPress? Qual versão do PHP? Qual o servidor?

Comment: Servidor da Dreamhost. Última versão estável do PHP. Linux.

Comment: Possuo uma outra instalação do Wordpress, e o mesmo não me deu problema algum...

Comment: o erro aconteceu de repente? estava normal e ficou ruim? você instalou algum plugin recentemente?

Comment: Não, ele está desde que subi o tema para o wordpress. Comecei a desenvolve-lo a poucos dias

Comment: se você usa o tema padrão por exemplo, você não tem esse problema? o upload ocorre normalmente? Você tem certeza que este tema foi desenvolvido para a mesma versão do WP que você está usando?

Comment: Usando os temas padrões, eu consigo inclusive, ver o que já foi inserido na mídia mas não ficou visível pra mim quando estava com meu tema desenvolvido.

Comment: verifique se o seu arquivo "functions.php" contém a seguinte linha
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );

Comment: Tinha inserido este código: <?php
/* IMAGEM DESTACADA NOS POSTS*/
  add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
 set_post_thumbnail_size( 120, 120 );

?>

Comment: definitivamente, o problema esta no seu tema, você precisa investigar o log de erros do servidor para ver se encontra alguma pista.

Comment: acabei de fazer um teste e deletei meu arquivo Functions e agora funcionou. Porém, meu arquivo só continha 1 linha de código, que era este de Imagem destacada.. O que você acha que deva ser?

Comment: Você deletou o functions.php e funcionou o upload da imagem destacada? ou você criou outro functions.php e adicionou novamente a linha da imagem destacada? Qual a versão do seu wordpress?

Comment: Wordpress Versão 4.4. Eu deletei o arquivo functions e consegui enviar imagens para a mídia. Recoloquei o arquivo Functions com apenas o código que você me informou, e agora apenas me retorna erro.

Comment: Qual erro? o mesmo?
tente retirar a tag de fechamento do php "?>" ela não é necessária. 
Pode ser algum conflito. Tente copiar o arquivo functions.php de outro tema e adicionar no seu. Qual editor de texto esta usando? Alguma IDE? Veja se ela esta salvando o arquivo no formato utf-8.

Comment: Consegui solucionar meu problema. Lhe agradeço a idéia de informar ao arquivo ser do tipo utf-8!

Comment: Oba! Sucesso ai rapaz!

Answer (score -1):

Aos que encontraram problemas no arquivo function, eu encontrei a solução para o meu problema, forçando no início meu arquivo a tag  
Acredito que algum caractere tenha impedido do wordpress efetuar a leitura deste arquivo, assim me barrando na hora de inserção ou visualização de arquivos na mídia.